# How do I get the top record from listagg in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the first record from the list return by listagg(). I have tried to use LIMIT, TOP, PARTITION but nothing is working for me.

The query is something like this:

```
select distinct(col1), col2, LISTAGG(col4, '; ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY....) 
from table1 inner join table 2 on ..
group by ....;
```

So, the query was to get all the records that are satisfying the conditions. Now, since I have the list, I need to provide the fix only for the latest record only.

Hope I am clear with what I am doing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sample data which demonstrates the problem you're having as well as desired output.

Comment: If you need only latest records , why manipulate on the records from `LISTAGG`? why not pick only the required record using `row_number()` or `rank()`

Comment: @KaushikNayak: Hi, I am very new to the DB part, I have just started. Thanks for the alternative you are suggesting. I wanted to get the latest record but I don't think I am on the right track. How do I get all the elements 
 apart from the latest from the listagg function in a substr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` :

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUBSTR(YourColumn, 0, INSTR(YourColumn, ',')-1) as newCol
FROM (Your Query Here) t
```

That is only if `col4` doesn't contain a comma.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me alot. I had one more issue here. How do I get values in a new column which are in listagg but not in the substr that I have created to fetch the latest records.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use `listagg()` for this?  Use `keep`:

```
SELECT MAX(COL4) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST col4 ORDER BY . . .)
```

Or, without the `GROUP BY`, you can just use the analytic function `FIRST_VALUE()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need `LISTAGG` for the first case. It is less efficient to extract from output of LISTAGG. Instead you can use `FIRST_VALUE`. For the second case you can use `row_number()` function  and aplply  `LISTAGG` on top as shown.

For selecting latest record use

```
SELECT t.*, FIRST_VALUE(col4) OVER( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ..) latest
FROM
  ( select id,col1,..col4 FROM.. ) t;
```

For selecting elements apart from the latest as `LISTAGG`, use

```
select id,LISTAGG(col4 ,';')  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY .. ) apart_from_latest FROM
 (
  SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ..) rn
FROM
  (  select id,col1,..col4 FROM.. ) t ) WHERE rn > 1 group BY ..;
```